# Mail server connection failed while configuring gmail at server but works perfectly on local machine

Tags: email, ssl, grails, groovy, grails-plugin

> Error:
>   org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;  nested exception is:  java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext). Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;  nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext); message exception details (1) are:Failed message 1:javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;  nested exception is:   java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1986)  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:656)  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345) at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder.sendMessage(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:131) at grails.plugin.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:55)   at grails.plugin.mail.MailService.sendMail(MailService.groovy:59)   at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.MailPluginMailStrategy.sendMail(MailPluginMailStrategy.groovy:50)   at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.MailPluginMailStrategy.sendVerifyRegistrationMail(MailPluginMailStrategy.groovy:34) at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController.sendVerifyRegistrationMail(RegisterController.groovy:79)  at register

```
config.groovy

mail {
   host = "smtp.gmail.com"
   port = 465
   username = "*******@gmail.com"
   password = "********"
   props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
}
```

Comment: Different jdk between Dev and live?

Comment: @tim_yates  both of my dev and live is 7.x  . Does this matter on mail ? Coz when i deploy the same war on my local machine, the apps works good but throws the above error when i deploy on server and try to send email.

Comment: NoSuchAlgorithmException - "This exception is thrown when a particular cryptographic algorithm is requested but is not available in the environment." -- there is a difference between what your local machine supports as SSL parameters and what your server supports. Perhaps the server admins restricted to TLSv1.2 and some subset of cipher suites. Talk to them.